# After binding Mac to AD, first login successfully creates mobile account and logs in, after that next login locks AD account

Tags: mac-osx, mobile-devices, accounts

Mac os x 10.7 and 10.8
AD Server 2008 R2
Binding using AD Plugin or dsconfigad -add mydomain -username myuser -ou "OU=Computers,OU=Sites,OU=Mysite,DC=mycompany,DC=com"

Works fine.  First login happens fine.  Creates mobile account, no issues noticed.  After I logout, the next login attempt fails, and after only shaking one time, their AD account is locked out.  opendirectory.log makes a vague mention of account being expired but honestly I don't see much in the logs that pops out as useful.

Any help?